# MYSQL : Connecting to mysql from : 127.0.0.1 + telling ip tables to allow only 127.0.0.1 for mysql port : Logic vs Common Sense

Tags: iptables, mysql, mysql-connection

> If i make 1 billion or 1 trillion queries to MYSQL database from 127.0.0.1 via port 3306.

vs

> If i make same amount of queries to MYSQL database also from 127.0.0.1 via
>   port 3306.

but with a difference thing. In this case I would have this rule in `iptables`:

```
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 3306 -s 127.0.0.1 -j ACCEPT
```

rather than the regular..

```
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
```

- Can there be any speed consequences ?
- Can there be any efficiency consequences ?

Because human mind says:

> how can there not be a consequence if it has to  be verified by the iptables 
>   that it actually is 127.0.0.1 and not some other İP address that is trying to establish a connection "

Comment: Use a unix socket instead of a TCP connection, this will reduce the TCP overhead and you don't need to use iptables rules.

Comment: Your most recent edit made the question worse. On your original question, I could mostly make sense of what you were saying. Your new question is very difficult to understand.

Answer (score 1):

With a huge traffics like billion or trillion, your second rule:

```
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 3306 -s 127.0.0.1 -j ACCEPT
```

might be slower, because it must compare source address of packets with `127.0.0.1`. While your first rule:

```
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
```

will accept all request to port 3306 from **anywhere**. This is a big hole in security, and you should not use this rule in production.